How Create Json Schema to validate based on type received
Below is the Json , I need to Check the type first if type is one i need to validate  only "one" :{payload} only and leave other two object two and three ,similarly for two and three. Any suggestion on how to create json Schema for this.
{
"operationType": {
"type": "1",
"description": "one"
},
"ID": "123",
"appid": "",
"one":
{
"startDateTime": "YYYY-MM-DDT08:00:00.000Z",
"endDateTime": "YYYY-MM-DDT08:00:00.000Z"
},
"two":
{
"Reason": " Requested",
"ReasonDetails": ""
},
"three":
{
"actualStartTime": "YYYY-MM-DDT08:00:00.000Z",
"actualEndTime": "YYYY-MM-DDT08:00:00.000Z"
}
}
tried:
"OneOf": [
   {
      "if": {
           "properties": {
                "operationType/type": { "enum": ["1"] }},
      "then": {
            "required": [ "one"]}
            
    }},
    {
     "if": {
            "properties": {
                "operationType/type": { "const": ["2"]}},
      "then": {
            "required": [ "two"]}
    }}
    ,
    {
     "if": {
            "properties": {
                "operationType/type": { "const": ["3"]}},
      "then": {
            "required": [ "three"]}
    }}
  ]


what have you tried?  Give some example and we can help you further
